# Spark 2.0 - pyspark2 data frame- -》unique id generation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, unique, apache-spark-sql

Using spark 2.0 with pyspark.

Source table is in hive
Target table is in hive

At target table want to create unique row_ids which will be unique increasing and it should not repeat.

Sample code

```
SourceDf=Spark.sql ("""select * from table""")
SouceDf.registerastemptable (souceDf)
Spark.sql (insert into targettable select 
Rowid,  a.col1, a.col2....from sourceDf
```

)

How to do the same ?

Comment: use `monotonicallyIncreasingId` function or `row_number` with an unpartitioned window (more expensive)

Comment: Monotonically will repeat ? May be in subsequent run , how monotonically would know what is already there in targt table.

Comment: First of all use `monotonically_increasing_id` instead of `monotonicallyIncreasingId` (deprecated) and if you get the highest value from your table at the start, you can add that (+1) to your monotonically_increasing_id

Answer (score 1):

You can use monotonically_increasing_id from [pyspark.sql.functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
with_id=SourceDF.withColumn('_id',monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Comment: Is this stable ?

Comment: it has been around since spark 1.6 (we're at 2.3.1 as of this comment)